# ufw is listening to tcp6 on OCI and cloudflare ssl certificate

Tags: 20.04, firewall, ipv6, ipv4

```
    netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.xx:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      809/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1916/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      2342/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      944/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1916/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      998/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::2052                 :::*                    LISTEN      998/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::2087                 :::*                    LISTEN      998/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      2342/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      998/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      998/apache2
```

so I tried to refix with ufw all the options available eg. disable then enable fixing back that ipv6 in ufw file but none came out definitive.

lets sharing details:

1. ssl / proxy clodflare
2. compute is with OCI
3. php v 7.4
4. elsticsearch 7.6.0
5. ubuntu 20.4

> ```
> sudo lsof -i:443
> COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> apache2  944        root   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> apache2  945    www-data   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> apache2  946    www-data   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> apache2  947    www-data   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> apache2  948    www-data   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> apache2  949    www-data   10u  IPv6  27489      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
> gomon   1987 snap_daemon   12u  IPv4  38550      0t0  TCP myhost.sub1234567890.someocivcn.oraclevcn.com:35072->someip:https
> ```
>
> (ESTABLISHED)

I added ip6 lists in ufw https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ but no luck.
so I have no way to verify the certificate with Cloudflare whole HTTP and HTTPS are down.

thx
sayantan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nowadays both should work with a webserver but

`vi /etc/sysctl.d/Diableipv6.conf`
add these below mentioned system parameters

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

but I added ONLY
`net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1`

it mostly worked in OCI based BMs or OCIs' ubuntu computes

ref: [for further reading and more info you may consider this links](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu)

thx